# Error in Fixed Effects Model

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, fixed-effects-model

I want to do a fixed effects model on a dummy dataset which has 3 columns depicting severity of patients and their survival rate in different hospitals.

[image]

The SURVIVALRATE is the dependent variable and SEVERITY as my independent variable with HOSPITAL column being the covariate having fixed effect.
I want only a fixed effects model and no random effects as I am trying to understand the difference between fixed effects and ols.

I tried using lme function and am getting this error

```
model_fixed1<-lme(SURVIVALRATE~SEVERITY,data=data_hos)
Error in getGroups.data.frame(dataMix, groups) : 
  invalid formula for groups
```

I also tried lmer function

```
model_fixed2<-lmer(SURVIVALRATE ~ SEVEREITY,data=data_hos)
Error: No random effects terms specified in formula
```

Is my syntax wrong? how do I do it.
Also if possible guide me how to do random effects from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such thing as a linear mixed model with only fixed effects. That's just linear regression/ordinary least squares, and you fit it using the `lm` function:

`model_fixed1<-lm(SURVIVALRATE~SEVERITY,data=data_hos)`